# Swift Pre-permission Overlay

Tags: swift, xcode, permissions, cllocationmanager, uialertcontroller

In my function where I get the user's location, I have created pre-permissions to have an alert before the authorization message to not lose the 1 chance to get the necessary permissions from the user.

```
func getCurrentLocation() {
// Init LocationManager
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 
kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Allow Loction Services?",
message: "This allows the app to your loction",
preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Allow", style: .default, handler: { 
(action) -> Void in
self.showHUD("loading...")

if locationManager.responds(to: 
#selector(CLLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}}
self.hideHUD()
)
}



let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Not Now", style: .destructive, 
handler: { (action) -> Void in })

alert.addAction(ok); alert.addAction(cancel)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

In the section:

`let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Allow", style: .default, handler: { 
    (action) -> Void in
    self.showHUD("loading...")`

An error pops us saying "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Answer (score 0):

The Swift compiler is giving you that error because the statement `self.hideHUD()` is outside of the braces that mark the completion handler block.

I suspect that instead of two curly braces on the line above, you want a single curly brace, with another coming *after* you hide the HUD:

```
.......
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    self.hideHUD()
}
........
```